# Website that contains the maps of atmospheric pressure and wind speeds

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, wind, tropical-cyclone, severe-weather

Is there a website that contains the maps of atmospheric pressure and wind speeds for specific climatic events such as hurricanes day after day ?

Comment: Is there a specific region and period of interest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this beta data portal from the Cooperative Institute for Meteorological Satellite Studies / University of Wisconsin-Madison
CIMSS Tropical Cyclones
Data Archive http://tropic.ssec.wisc.edu/archive/  .

However, my favorite source of information is the Regional and Mesoscale Meteorology Branch (RAMMB) of NOAA/NESDIS http://rammb.cira.colostate.edu/products/tc_realtime/

And there are good summaries here:
https://www.tropicalstormrisk.com/hislink.html

and another good general source of information is from the National Hurricane Center http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/data/

Comment: UCAR provides some data at http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/imagearchive/ and for nice visualizations http://earth.nullschool.net lets you browse back in time.