# Where can I get archived hourly wind speed data for Germany?

Tags: meteorology, wind, open-data

Can some one suggest me a web site for archived hourly wind data for Germany.

I have seen [here](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/6740/website-that-contains-the-maps-of-atmospheric-pressure-and-wind-speeds) but it was not useful for me.

Comment: I assume you're familiar with ISD? ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/

Comment: A useful option for those looking at specific events\times is also www.wunderground.com, though it looks like it only goes back 20 years at WMO sites versus full records in US.  To find official data, type in the city and hit enter... then click the link to the right of the airplane icon on the left top under the city name [for instance, I want Berlin, type Berlin, then click Kegel], and it'll give you history to select from.  Can also get unofficial local sites, though they're less standardized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most authoritative source for weather data in Germany is the German Weather Service (DWD). They have a climate data center that by now provides historical data free of charge. You can find it here: http://www.dwd.de/EN/climate_environment/cdc/cdc_node.html (it appears some knowledge of German might be helpful.)

Answer (score 7):

The [MERRA](http://gmao.gsfc.nasa.gov/research/merra/) dataset has data for the world from 1979 to date. It updates frequently.

You can get the data as HDF or NETCDF. If your GIS package doesn't read those, there will be translation packages around the web to convert them into a suitable format.

You'll want the U- and V- wind data. You might want pressure too. And possibly even turbulence data.

If you're interested in using this for simulating wind generation, then I highly recommend [the paper by Cannon et al on analysing the MERRA data for wind energy simulation](http://www.met.reading.ac.uk/~energymet/data/Cannon2015/).

You might also be interested in the [CFSR](http://cfs.ncep.noaa.gov/cfsr/) data, which runs 1979-2010: in connection with using this paper for wind energy simulation, see [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.renene.2014.12.025) by Sharp et al.

([I've previously posted this elsewhere on StackExchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/5602/530))

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply. I am working on MERRA data. I just wanted some other source to authenticate my piece of work.