# CFSR hourly surface wind time series

Tags: wind, open-data, reanalysis

I am looking for hourly surface wind reanalysis data for the past two years. I am looking at the CFSR/CFSv2 data accessible from UCAR:
http://rda.ucar.edu/datasets/ds094.1

The 6-hourly products are "complete" (http://rda.ucar.edu/datasets/ds093.0/), while the hourly dataset (http://rda.ucar.edu/datasets/ds094.1) is "Selected". I take "Selected" to mean a subset of some kind. For those familiar with CFSR, what exactly is selected, and what is not contained in the dataset?

Suggestions on other sources of hourly reanalysis surface wind datasets would be appreciated as well.

Comment: You can find info on other sources [here](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/7331/100) . In short - MERRA,

Answer (score 1):

If you check the 6-hourly products in the links you shared, you can see that CFSR includes 50 variables in the "complete" dataset. The hourly dataset has a limited number of variables (25 in total). That's what they mean by "selected". Hope this help.